# Как вывести время, которое было 15 минут назад на Bash?

Tags: bash

Нужно вывести время, которое было 15 минут назад.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
date --date '-15 min'
```

Если нужно только время, то так:

```
date --date '-15 min' +%R
```

Comment: Да, работает, только нужно только время без даты, тоже самое сделать с `date +%R` не получается)

Comment: @Dofri, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

чтобы средствами программы *bash* произвести такой подсчёт **корректно**, нужен, вероятно, довольно большой и «развесистый» скрипт.

но если вы используете *posix-совместимую* операционную систему, можно воспользоваться программой *date*.

к сожалению, в самом стандарте для этой программы подобной функциональности [не предусмотрено](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html).

но, например, в [*bsd-реализации*](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=date&category=1&russian=1) можно написать [так](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126303/110559):

```
$ date -v -15M
```

а в [реализации](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) для операционной системы *gnu*, например, [так](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation):

```
$ date -d 'now - 15 min'
```

---

формат вывода можно задать опцией `+формат`. например, так:

```
$ date '+%H:%M' ...
12:47
```

Answer (score 1):

проверил на Debian 8.
только время (часы-минуты-секунды)

```
dt3d=$(date --date="15 minutes ago" +"%H-%M-%S")
echo $dt3d
```

дата (год.месяц.число-часы-минуты-секунды)

```
dt3d1=$(date --date="15 minutes ago" +"%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
echo $dt3d1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date --date '-15 min'| awk '{print $4}'
```